# C++ "=" operator behavior for a class with a private vector and iterator for it

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, operator-overloading

I'm trying to make an object that gives sequentially an output but I don't want to expose the inner implementation. I want the other classes to see just the methods hasNextOutput() and nextOutput(). Here is my header file and class file respectively:

header file:

```
#ifndef RADAR_OUTPUT_GENERATOR_H
#define RADAR_OUTPUT_GENERATOR_H

#include<vector>
#include<iterator>
#include "asl/include/net/asl_net_user_data.h"

class RadarOutputGenerator {
private:
    int dataCounter;    
    std::vector<unsigned char *> dataStream;
    std::vector<unsigned char *>::iterator dataStreamIterator;
public:
    RadarOutputGenerator();
    RadarOutputGenerator(char *filename);
    RadarOutputGenerator(unsigned int maxDataSize);
    ~RadarOutputGenerator();

    bool hasNextOutput();
    void nextOutput(unsigned char *&dataWithHeader);
};

#endif
```

The class implementation

```
#include "radar_output_generator.h";

RadarOutputGenerator::RadarOutputGenerator() {

}

RadarOutputGenerator::RadarOutputGenerator(unsigned int maxDataSize) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        // create some data

        this->dataStream.push_back(data);

        cur_step = (cur_step += 10) & 65535;
    }

    this->dataStreamIterator = (this->dataStream).begin();
}

bool RadarOutputGenerator::hasNextOutput() {
    return (this->dataStreamIterator != this->dataStream.end());
}

void RadarOutputGenerator::nextOutput(unsigned char *&dataWithHeader) {
    dataWithHeader = *(this->dataStreamIterator++);
}
```

The problem is that when I construct an object of type RadarOutputGenerator, the hasNext() method fails on "iterators incompatible" error, e.g. this code fails:

```
RadarOutputGenerator myOutputGenerator = RadarOutputGenerator(47);
radarOutputGenerator.hasNextOutput(); // this line fails
```

I think I see where is the problem - probably when invoking the "=" operator the vector dataStream is copied and the iterator initialized in the constructor keeps the reference to the original vector. If that's the case, this behaviour kind of dissapoints me but I'd like to know, how to fix this problem properly.

Comment: Just so you know, when you define and initialize an object like that you're not invoking the assignment operator, but the *copy constructor*. And you "fix" the problem by implementing a copy constructor *and* an assignment operator (please read about the [rules of three, five and zero](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)).

Comment: You need to either overload the copy assignment operator and the copy constructor (and move-assignment and move-copy), or ditch the iterator and use an index instead.

Comment: Another possibility is to use a shared_ptr to the vector, so that all generators copied from each other use the same data stream. If you ever need to modify the stream in the middle of an iteration, make it copy-on-write.

Comment: I can't quite see what your requirements are. Are you looking to transform a stream into a sequence of packets?

Comment: I don't have any stream, maybe a file containing the individual packets already, but I didn't mention it in the question because I didn't consider it relevant. The main purpose of this class is just to generate a sequence of valid packets following a protocol of a specific hardware device (a radar) and my first approach is just to generate those in the constructor and store them in a vector which will be later iterated over to retrieve the individual packets in a sequential order. But if you have any tips on how to improve the code, I would appreciate it, even if it isn't the main topic.

Comment: The incentive is, that the actual data are quite "expensive" (you need to wait for good weather, take out the radar...) and I can have just a limited amount of them, so to test the remaining components of the whole system I'd like to have a cheaper and more flexible resource of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to solve this is to overload the copy constructor and copy assignment operator to do the right thing, i.e. compute the offset of the iterator into the old vector, and create a new iterator that points that far into the new vector.

As a general rule, whenever an object has an interior pointer (something that refers to a part of itself), you will need to implement copying manually.

A simpler solution, but not as universally applicable, is to do as n.m. said in the comments and store an index instead of an iterator. An index is not associated with a particular vector.